# How to create new list with any enter to for-loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

i want after end second for-loop the create new list, in other words when j increment define new list

the code is:

```
for j in range(0, countOfAtt):
    for i in range(j, len(content3), countOfAtt):
        list1.append(content3[i])
```

thank you in advance

Comment: can you be more clear?

Comment: i want create new list with new name for example : j = 0 list1.append() then j =1 list2.append() and continue to end of for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
final_list = []  # this will hold all the lists you created in for loop
for j in range(0, countOfAtt):
    mylist = []   # initiate a new list
    for i in range(j, len(content3), countOfAtt):
        mylist.append(content3[i])
    final_list.append(mylist)
```

Comment: Please provide more context and details to your question so I can update the answer

Comment: i want create new list with new name for example : j = 0 list1.append() then j =1 list2.append() and continue to end of for-loop

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a new list (with whatever you were trying to put in it) for every `j`:

```
[[content3[i] for i in range(j, len(content3), countOfAtt)] for j in range(countOfAtt)]
```

If it doesn't give you what you want, then you'll have to show samples of the data you have before the loops, and of the output you desire, so we could check the logic.

Comment: thanks but i don't understand your answer ... please explain more.

Comment: @amin It's basically exactally what Zeeshan wrote, but in a much cooler (and faster) pythonic way. Google for `python list comprehension` to learn about it.